How can `if constexpr` be made SFINAE-friendly?
I have a code using "classic" SFINAE.
template<class M> auto power(M const& elem) -> decltype(std::norm(elem)) { return std::norm(elem); }

template<class M, class = std::enable_if_t<(M::rank::value >= 1)>>
auto power(M const& array) {
    return accumulate(begin(array), end(array), 0.0, [](auto const& alpha, auto const& omega) { return alpha + power(omega); });
}

This is a recursive (across dimensions or ranks) "power" function that ultimately gives the sum of the squares of the elements by calculating the power of subelements of lower dimension.
Modern C++ incentivizes the use if constexpr to avoid using SFINAE, like below.
template<class M>
auto power(M const& array) {
    if constexpr(M::rank::value >= 1) {
        return accumulate(begin(array), end(array), 0.0, [](auto const& alpha, auto const& omega) { return alpha + power(omega); });
    } else {
        return std::norm(array);
    }
}

The problem is that it seems that the expression in the if constexpr has to be a valid expression in the first place.
Elements don't have a member type called rank, so there is a compilation error.
Is there a trick to make the if constexpr predicate if the expression is invalid?

if constexpr is not SFINAE at all (maybe just a way to get "nicer" compiler errors).  The compiler will still consider your second power function in overload resolution, while SFINAE ensures that functions are really not considered. So stick with std::enable_if_t (or concepts in C++20)

If you want if constexpr to check a struct is valid, you need requires expressions.

if constexpr kind of allows for partial specialization of templated functions. To replace SFINAE you need C++20 concepts.

C++20 and newer:
if constexpr (requires{requires std::bool_constant</*condition*/>::value;})

There's also a less verbose option:
if constexpr (requires{requires /*condition*/;})

But the latter is worse, because it causes a hard error if the condition is not known at compile-time, while the former just returns false.
The former is used in the standard library (see also In a nested requirement, why use requires bool_constant<X>::value; instead of requires X;?).
C++17:
Use the detection idiom:
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename ...P> struct void_type {using type = void;};

    template <typename DummyVoid, template <typename...> typename A, typename ...B> struct is_detected : std::false_type {};
    template <template <typename...> typename A, typename ...B> struct is_detected<typename void_type<A<B...>>::type, A, B...> : std::true_type {};
}

template <template <typename...> typename A, typename ...B>
inline constexpr bool is_detected = detail::is_detected<void, A, B...>::value;

Then:
template <typename M>
using CheckRank = std::enable_if_t<M::rank::value >= 1>;

if constexpr (is_detected<CheckRank, M>)


Sorry, I forgot to add the C++17 tag. But good to know for C++20.

@alfC Alright, see edit.

@alfC in general please refrain from updating a question in a way that invalidates exitsing correct answer(s).

@wohlstad, yes, sorry about that, I had that in mind since the start and at the last minute forgot to add the tag. Fortunately, the answer is valid for both versions.

This reminded me that std::experimental::is_detected existed. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected . It seems that it never made it to the standard. Will this work with short-circuiting? or I will have write another nested if constexpr ? Looks like the latter.

@alfC Yeah, this works the same way as std::experimental::is_detected. if constexpr (A && B) won't short-circuit, but if you move && to enable_if_t it will.
